# echoprint-codegen runs indefinitely with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, delayed-job, system-calls

I'm attempting to run `echoprint-codegen` in a background process for analysing audio files as they're uploaded to a web service.

The desired functionality exists with a simple system call to the tmp file that gets uploaded via paperclip:

`` result = `echoprint-codegen #{path} 0 20` # works! ``

Unfortunately, this is not the case when the delayed workers fire off a new job;  the `echoprint-codegen` process appears to hang indefinitely.

Per the `echoprint` README, I've double checked that `ffmpeg` is also within the path (Paperclip.options[:command_path] is pointing to the correct path).

I've also attempted to encapsulate the `echoprint-codegen` command line in a `Paperclip.run()` call, but that also results in a hanging process.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have obtained desired functionality by placing the echoprint-codegen system call in a Ruby Thread:

```
thread = Thread.new { Thread.current[:result] = `echoprint-codegen #{path} 0 20` }
thread.join
result = thread[:result]
```